# The square map on $SO(n)$

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, lie-groups, covering-spaces, equivariant-maps

Let  $P:SO(n) \to  SO(n)$  be  the  square  map  $P(A)=A^2$.

Does  $P$  define  a  covering  map  structure?

If  yes, is there  an  action of  a finite group  $G$ on  $SO(n)$ such that each fiber of the  covering  space is  a  $G$-orbit  and  each  orbit  is  a  fiber??

If  yes,  can the  tangent  bundles of  $SO(n)$ be acted  by  $G$  such that we  obtain a  $G$  bundle  structure?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It can't be a covering map for $n>2$, since the fundamental group of $SO(n)$ for $n>2$ is finite, hence it can't cover itself with more than one sheet. But note that $P(I)=I$ and $P(A)=I$, where $$A=\begin{pmatrix} -1 & 0 &0 & \cdots & 0  \\
0 &-1 & 0 &\cdots &0 \\
0 &0 & 1 &\cdots & 0 \\
0 &0 &0 &\cdots &1 \end{pmatrix}.$$

For $n=2$, $SO(n)$ is $S^1$, so the map is a covering map.

For $n=1$, it is the identity, so the map is a covering map.

Comment: This is technically correct but kinda non-constructive. It is interesting to understand where this map fails to be a covering.

Comment: ...for $n \geq 3$. $SO(2)$ is a circle.

Comment: @Wolfram I admit this answer very much leaves me wondering that. Is part of the issue that it's not 2-to-1 but actually infinity-to-one for $n\gt 2$? (For instance, there are infinitely many $M\in SO(3)$ with $M^2=I$: take the rotation of 180 degrees about any axis; then this fixes exactly two antipodal points and is uniquely determined by the points it fixes.)

Comment: @StevenStadnicki Indeed. If we take the rotations with close axes we get very close elements from the preimage of $I$, so the preimage is not discrete $\Rightarrow$ not a covering. $SO(n)$ can be handled just padding the matrices for $SO(3)$ with $1$s on the diagonal.

Answer (score 3):

There are several obstructions to this map being a covering map for $n \ge 3$. A simple one is that its fibers are not discrete: for example, $P^{-1}(I)$ contains all $180^{\circ}$ rotations about every axis.

Alternatively, you can use the fact that a map between closed manifolds is a covering map iff it's a local diffeomorphism, and then compute the differential of $P$ to see where it fails to be a local diffeomorphism. The tangent space at an element $X \in SO(n)$ can be identified with the set of matrices of the form $X(I + \epsilon Y)$ where $Y \in \mathfrak{so}(n)$ is a skew-symmetric matrix and $\epsilon^2 = 0$. Squaring such a matrix gives

$$\left( X + \epsilon XY \right)^2 = X^2 + \epsilon (X^2 Y + XYX) = X^2 \left( I + \epsilon (Y + X^{-1} Y X) \right).$$

So the differential $P_X$ can be identified with the linear map $Y \mapsto Y + X^{-1} Y X$. This is an isomorphism iff it has nontrivial kernel, and its kernel consists of matrices $Y$ satisfying $Y + X^{-1} Y X = 0$.

The matrices $Y$ such that some $X$ exists with this property are matrices conjugate to $-Y$ by an element of $SO(n)$. Every skew-symmetric matrix $Y$ is conjugate to $-Y$, even by an element of $O(n)$, as follows: $Y$ is conjugate via an element of $O(n)$ to a block diagonal matrix whose blocks have the form

$$\left[ \begin{array}{cc} 0 & \theta \\ - \theta & 0 \end{array} \right]$$

for some $\theta$, and any such block is conjugate to its negation via a reflection. The extra condition that we need $Y$ to be conjugate to $-Y$ via an element of $SO(n)$ means we need to do an even number of reflections, which is always possible when $n \ge 4$. When $n = 3$ one of the eigenvalues of $Y$ is zero and so we can just stick a $-1$ into $X$ as necessary.

Hence for any nonzero value of $Y$ we can find $X$ with the above property, and so there are many points at which the differential fails to be surjective and hence when $P$ fails to be a local diffeomorphism.

Comment: Thanks  for  the  answer.  So  my  question was a  trivial question since  I  did not  pay  attention to the (infinitness )  of  level sets.  But how  can  we  compare two typical  level sets(Are they the same topologicaly?). Do we have  a  (at  least topological) fiber bundle?

Comment: @Ali: no, you can also find some fibers that are discrete (take the preimage of something with distinct eigenvalues).

Comment: What  about the  square  map  on  $S^{3}$?Are there  two  different  fubers(topologically)?

Comment: @Ali: yes, the situation is basically the same as for $SO(3)$, you can consider e.g. the preimage of the identity and of an element with distinct eigenvalues.

Comment: Thanks  again for your  answer. I  am sorry that I  can not accept two answers. Just  a  question on your statement "...map between closed manifolds is a covering map iff it's a local diffeomorphism".  Can  not one modify  $x\mapsto  x^3$ on $\mathbb{R}$  to a  simillar example on a  closed manifold?